# How to represent Observable.empty() with LiveData in Android?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-jetpack, reactivex

Rx has `Observable.empty()` that represents nothing will be notified.

Is there an equivalent class (or something) in Android Architecture Components LiveData?

Answer (score 0):

You will always get the currently set value on observing.

Therefore, your best bet is either to handle `null` values, or use `LiveData<Optional<T>>` (or, in Kotlin, `LiveData<T?>`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that you want to expose a LiveData that indicates to the caller that it will never emit a value, I don't think you have a way to express that with architecture components, since LiveData can always emit values of its generic type.

You could use `LiveData<Void>` in Java or `LiveData<Unit>` in Kotlin to say that the emitted values have no type, but I believe they can still be observed, and its observers can still be triggered with values that contain no data.  LiveData doesn't have a concept of saying "I'm done and I will never emit anything ever again".  A Kotlin [Flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html) might be better for that case, since a Flow can complete with no more emissions.